# How to map field values while converting message JSON<->SOAP

Tags: wso2-esb

I need to map values of several fields while message is sending from one system to another. For example receive SOAP message with status "START" and produce JSON message with status "BEGIN".
Is it possible to do this with WSO2 ESB (or with some help from other WSO2 products)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [PayloadFactory](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/PayloadFactory+Mediator) and [Switch](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Switch+Mediator) mediator. 
A simple example:

```
<switch source="//status">
  <case regex="START">
    <property name="status" scope="default" type="STRING" value="BEGIN"/>
  </case>
  <default>
    <property expression="//status" name="status" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
  </default>
</switch>
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
  <format>
    {"status": $1}
  </format>
  <args>
    <arg expression="get-property('status')"/>
  </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

I hope this helps.